GRUB removed after windows update
I have a dual boot dell XPS laptop with windows and Ubuntu 22. After the latest windows update GRUB is no longer in the boot options of the BIOS. I have also tried inserting a live USB of Ubuntu 22 and running boot-repair to no avail. Here is the log link:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fnGZXVXfyJ/
Any help is appreciated.

Everything looks correct, except no UEFI boot entry for Ubuntu. You can from Ubuntu live installer use efibootmgr to reinstall an UEFI entry or use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub as that also is what its default fix is. If using efibootmgr you have to specify NVMe drive & partition. See VI https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

So after a bit of searching this solution helped:
https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-grub-not-showing-in-dual-boot-setup/
I ended up running bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi in a privileged CMD on windows to add GRUB to the boot list.
somehow boot-repair couldn't fix this.
